# Laravel 6 - No se recibe el array correspondiente al subir datos a tabla SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-6

El siguiente código se supone que recibe la ID más reciente de una tabla SQL (que lo logra), pasarlo a un array (que lo logra (duplicado por ahora)) y por ultimo subirlo a una tabla distinta...lo cual no lo logra, generando el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error indica que que el primer campo de la tabla, "proyecto_id", no tiene un valor default, es decir, que no esta recibiendo información. Sin embargo, de acuerdo al siguiente código, se supone que si recibe:

```php
public function store(Request $request){

        $request->validate([
            'nombre_imagen' => ['required'],
            'extension_archivo' => ['required'],
            'alto' => ['required'],
            'ancho' => ['required'],
        ]);

        //Imagenes_Descripcion::create($request->all());

        $data_img = DB::table('imagenes__descripcions')
                ->max('id');

        $data_img_array = [$data_img, $data_img];

        Imagenes_Descripcion_Plantillas::create($data_img_array);
```

Incluso, pensé que el array estaba incorrecto, así que usé la función "dd($data_img_array);" para ver si ese era el caso, sin embargo...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El array efectivamente tiene 2 ID's. Por ende no entiendo que es lo que puede estar mal.

También pense en usar un array de 1 objeto y ponerlo 2 veces en el create, así:

```php
$data_img_array = [$data_img];

Imagenes_Descripcion_Plantillas::create($data_img_array,$data_img_array);
```

Y recibí los mismos errores.

¿Hay algo que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Tendrías que pasarle el array con los pares clave/valor correspondientes a los atributos del modelo. Ej: `$data_img_array = ['producto_id' => $data_img, 'otro atributo' => $data_img];`

Comment: @Hugo, vemos que has publicado muchas preguntas, pero la gran mayoría se quedan sin respuesta porque no aportas detalles cuando te los solicitan. Por favor, ten en cuenta que aquí colaboramos de forma voluntaria, y lo menos que esperamos es que también pongas de tu parte.

Comment: @porloscerros Ψ Muchas gracias, probe lo que me dijiste y sirvió de manera inmediata! Gran manera de partir mi dia de trabajo. De nuevo, muchas gracias

Comment: Hugo, me alegro que te haya servido. De todas maneras presta atención a lo que te dice @Shaz. En cuanto tengas tiempo, revisa en tu [perfil](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/123407/hugo?tab=questions) las preguntas que vas dejando abiertas, e intenta cerrarlas, ya sea con respuestas (tuyas o de otros usuarios) o directamente eliminarlas si ya no tienen sentido. Ahora estoy escribiendo desde el móvil como para escribir una respuesta, en cuanto llegue al ordenador escribiré una si es que no lo hace alguien antes.

Comment: Te invito tambien a leer [Los valores fundamentales](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/key-values) y el [Manifiesto de Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto), que aunque no todos tenemos las mismas motivaciones, implícitamente concidimos en esto al estar aquí. Saludos.

Comment: De hecho intente borrar una pregunta que era estupida, pero el mismo sitio no me dejo con el mensaje "hay gente que respondio y puede ayudar a otros". Y es como...haber, quieren que borre algo pero el mismo sitio no me deja borrarlo.

Comment: Ok, no hay problema, lo que te permita el sitio, lo del bot son mensajes automáticos para mejorarlo. Considera dar un feedback a comentarios y respuestas, así también quien respondió puede mejorar su respuesta o eliminarla, y quienes te hacen comentarios no piensen que los estás ignorando. Tal cual cómo lo estás haciendo ahora. Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de hacerlo. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una vez que hayas definido en tu modelo los atributos que pueden asignarse en masa, puedes usar el método de `create()` para insertar un nuevo registro en la base de datos, al que deberás pasarle un array con los pares clave/valor correspondientes a los atributos del modelo.

Ej:

```
$flight = App\Flight::create(['name' => 'Flight 10']);
```

O para tu caso supongo que sería:

```
$la_instancia_del_modelo_guardado = Imagenes_Descripcion_Plantillas::create([
    'producto_id' => $data_img, 
    'otro atributo' => 'otro_valor'
]);
```